# How to add a variable to a route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and am a little caught up in how routing works. Currently, my route contains the subject name of a class, but I'd also like it to contain the professor ID.

how can I accomplish this if the subject name and the professor ID are from 2 different models?

So, for example, I'm currently routing the subject name by doing this:

```
@model List<CourseModel>

<h1>
    @foreach (var course in Model)
    {
    <a asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SubjectName="@course.SubjectName"> @course.SubjectName </a>
    <br />
    }
</h1>
```

However, as I stated above, the professor ID I'd like to put in the routing is from another model (but I can only call one model in a view) so I feel a bit stuck.

The code I have above is the professor/details view, so I feel like it should be simple to pull data from the professor controller, but I must be mistaken. the variable in the Professor controller is called "ID" but I can't seem to access it in the view when trying to put the value of it in the routing link.

Any suggestions? I'd appreciate any at all

Comment: As @Isparia shared, you can try to create and use a viewmodel to pass it. Besides, you can also [pass data through viewdata or viewbag from controller to view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#passing-data-from-the-controller-to-the-view).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this you should have a model like this, since you are in a details view of the professor, which teaches n courses.

```cs
public class ProfessorDetailsViewModel
{
    /*
       All the Professor Properties
    */
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<CourseViewModel> Courses {get; set}
}
```

and then you could use your razor view like this:

```
@model ProfessorDetailsViewModel

<h1>
    @foreach (var course in Model.Courses)
    {
    <a asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index" asp-route-SubjectName="@course.SubjectName" asp-route-ProfessorId="@Model.Id"> @course.SubjectName </a>
    <br />
    }
</h1>
```